# LINQ Named parameters with spaces

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
from c in Query
select new {User Name = c.UserName};
```

In LINQ I want to give the named arguments like this but it is not accepting `User Name` instead accepting `UserName`.

Answer (score 5):

No, it won't - that's not a valid C# identifier. You can't do that.

Don't try to make the *presentation* names the same as identifiers. You should use some translation layer to go from property names to labels for the UI, etc.

Comment: Hey I want to add spaces in between I can change the presentation names and the identifier.

Comment: @BALAMURUGAN: Well you simply can't. So don't try to. Separate the two concepts (property name in code; presentation name in UI) and map between the two where you have to.

Comment: Is there any simple way I want to get this named parameters and write in file as header.

Comment: @BALAMURUGAN: Well how were you getting the properties out anyway? Assuming you've got strings via reflection, just use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to map them.

Comment: I have my constructed query with 15 fields with header informations. And I am using reflection to write them to excel sheet.

Comment: @BALAMURUGAN: Right... so you already have the field names as strings, so it'll be really easy to just map them in a dictionary as you go.

Comment: How can I do this generically?

Comment: @BALAMURUGAN: I don't understand... you build a dictionary which maps property names to the header names. What are you finding difficult?

Comment: Hey, I have my query with header and data rows. Also my replacement dictionary object      Dictionary<string, string> dtyHeaderNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    dtyHeaderNames.Add("UserID", "User Name");
                 How can I replace the query with Dictionary values?

Comment: @BALAMURUGAN: When you iterate through the properties in the returned data, you map each property name to the header name, and then write out that header name.